# Does "gbm" package in R has basis functions other than decision tree?

Tags: r, gbm

if not, which packages implement multiple basis functions for boosting methods. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like it since you need to specify the number of trees in the gbm call.  You can try the 'mboost' package to specify different types of base learners.